# In VIM, tabs and spaces are highlighted at the beginning of each line, how can I get rid of this?

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, vi

I have tried using the *:noh* to get rid off the highlighting before the beginning of each line. But this highlighting seems to be different than the usual search one.

Any ideas how can I disable this feature?

Comment: It is either matches highlighting, or syntax highlighting. Your symptoms cannot be ever caused by `list` option as it can 'highlight' tabs and *trailing* spaces. So, post output of `echo 'Normal '.join(map(synstack(line('.'), col('.')+1), 'synIDattr(v:val, "name")'))` and `echo getmatches()` while cursor is on one of the highlighted symbols.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My .vimrc had the line below:

```
highlight Tabs ctermbg=1
match Tabs "\t"
```

This was highlighting the initial Tab characters in my source.

Answer (score 1):

Did you, by any chance, set the `list` option? Try to deactivate it by setting:

```
set nolist
```